# How to get full path of a loaded .NET framework DLL while debugging a Windows Phone App?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, windows-phone-7, visual-studio-debugging

I'm writing a Visual Studio extension and I noticed that when debugging a Windows Phone 7 App in the emulator, unlike in any other type of application, the VS Debugger isn't getting full path of many .NET framework DLLs, but just the name of the DLL itself, such as "System.dll":

[image: Modules window]

For my extension to work, I need the full path of each and every loaded DLL. My question is, how do I find out the full path that the app is taking that "System.dll" from?

Answer (score 1):

The assembly is loaded from the Windows Phone emulator image, it wouldn't be on your hard drive. You're essentially remote-debugging the emulator machine.

Answer (score 0):

How about this? Seems like it should work for anything running in the current AppDomain. Let me know if this helps.

```
        foreach (System.Reflection.Assembly assembly in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
        {
            string fullPath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(assembly.GetName().CodeBase);
        }
```

Comment: Thanks but it looks the Assembly.Location property doesn't exist in the Compact Framework, so can't be used in Windows Phone projects.

Comment: Interesting, please see the revised code and let me know if that gets to your path.

Comment: Thanks but no, that only gets me "\\windows\\GAC_System.Core_v3_7_0_0_cneutral_1.dll". I don't know what that is exactly, but in any case there's no such DLL on my system.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Assembly.Location` property. Use `Assembly.GetAssembly(Type type)` to get the assembly you need.

Comment: Thanks but it looks the Assembly.Location property doesn't exist in the Compact Framework, so can't be used in Windows Phone projects.